# Generating parser:didMatchInterior: callbacks

Tags: parsekit

I'm generating a static parser using ParserGenApp. The generated code contains assembler callbacks in the form 'parser:didMatch[Rule]:'. However, in your JavaScriptSyntaxParser in DempApp the callbacks have the form 'parser:didMatchInterior:' and alike. Can I get ParserGenApp to generate such calls? Or did you add them manually?

Thanks/Mikael

Comment: *Whose* JavaScriptSyntaxParser?  This isn't going directly to whatever team implemented parsekit or its demos, it's going to a generic programming community.  Can you give a pointer?  Also, it would be helpful to include a a few lines of your code, instead of simply describing it.

Answer (score 0):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

The key is the setting of the **"Post Match Callbacks"** popup.

By default, the ParserGenApp is configured to produce the normal `parser:didMatch[Rule]:` callbacks. These are useful for most applications. (this is the **"on All"** setting).

But you are looking for the **syntax tree** callbacks like `parser:didMatchInterior:` and `parser:didMatchLeaf:`.

To generate the syntax tree callbacks, change the "Post Match Callbacks" popup to the **"on Syntax"** option. And regenerate.